# Disable callout parsing in asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoctor

I have this source code

```
  def 'strict matcher'() {
    expect:
    assertRendered({
      // tag::strict-matcher[]
      def x = [2, 2, 1, 3, 3]
      assert x ==~ [4, 1, 2]
      // end::strict-matcher[]
    },
      /* tag::strict-matcher-result[] */ """
x ==~ [4, 1, 2]
| |
| false
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3]

Expected: iterable with items [<4>, <1>, <2>] in any order
     but: not matched: <2>
    """ // end::strict-matcher-result[]
    )
  }
```

which I include into an asciidoctor document with

```
[source,indent=0]
----
include::{sourcedir}/utilities/CollectionConditions.groovy[tag=strict-matcher-result]
----
```

The problem is, that Asciidoctor interprets the `<2>` as a callout turning it into a bold `(2)`.

```
x ==~ [4, 1, 2]
| |
| false
[2, 2, 1, 3, 3]

Expected: iterable with items [<4>, <1>, <2>] in any order
     but: not matched: (2)
```

I haven't found a way to include it `verbatim`, while also disabling callout processing.
I can't really put anything after the `<2>` as this is making sure that both strings match.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible, but a [feature request](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/3333) is filed in the backlog.